# Run .vbs within subfolder

Tags: windows, vbscript

Right now if I run a VBScript from a VBScript like this:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run("""runscript.vbs""")
```

This opens up `runscript.vbs`, which works!

If a create a subfolder to put the VBScript and reference it like below:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run("""x64/runscript.vbs""")
```

No error, but the script doesn't open like it should.

I know absolute path would work, but for the purpose of the script I can't use absolute path.

Comment: Did you try backslash? `x64\runscript.vbs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of the following should work.

1. Use a backslash instead of a forward slash:

   ```
   CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "x64\runscript.vbs"
   ```
2. Use the `CurrentDirectory` property to set the working folder:

   ```
   With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
       .CurrentDirectory = "x64"
       .Run "runscript.vbs"
   End With
   ```

Comment: The  backslash worked thanks to @JosefZ. . Thanks for the other option!